# Using html tags in hebrew language strings that are defined as JLabel text Makes the program load slower

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, hebrew

I have a problem in my program that I'm writing:
I'm creating 3 objects type of `JLabel`, and I'm using as hebrew language strings. I concatenate each string with an opening HTML tag and a closing HTML tag to enable multi-line text.

The problem is that when I'm using HTML tags, concatenate HTML tags to strings and set them as JLabels text, it takes about 6 seconds from running the program until the window appears. When I do not use the HTML tags, the window is displayed within one to two seconds after running the program.

Why is it like this? How can I use HTML tags with strings as JLabel text without having so big delay from starting the program until the programs window appears?

operating system: windows 10
compiler: Intellij IDEA

The code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GuideUseWin extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private BoxLayout mainLayout;
    private JLabel firstImgLbl;
    private JLabel secondImgLbl;
    private JLabel thierdImgLbl;


    public GuideUseWin() {
        this.setSize(400, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.mainPanel = new JPanel();
        this.mainLayout = new BoxLayout(this.mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        this.mainPanel.setLayout(this.mainLayout);
        this.add(this.mainPanel);
        this.firstImgLbl = new JLabel();

        ArrayList <JLabel> photosLblsArr = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        photosLblsArr.add(this.firstImgLbl);
        photosLblsArr.add(this.secondImgLbl);
        photosLblsArr.add(this.thierdImgLbl);

        String[] stepsArr = {"מדריך שימוש בסיסי בתוכנה ",
            "תחילה יש לבחור X מתוך 3 השורות המוצגות בחלון  התוכנית, על ידי לחיצה על אחד המקשים 1,2 או 3 במקלדת הנומרית",
            "לאחר מכן, יש לבחור מספר  על ידי לחיצה על אחד המקשים 0-9 "};

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JLabel stepLbl = new JLabel("<html>" + stepsArr[i] + "</html>");
            stepLbl.setForeground(Color.black);
            stepLbl.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            stepLbl.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            stepLbl.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
            stepLbl.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            this.mainPanel.add(stepLbl);

        }

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I checked and found out that when I'm using strings only in English language, the window is shown properly after 1-3 seconds after running the program. Why is it like this? And how can I use HTML tags with strings as JLabel text without having so big delay from starting the program until the programs window appears?

Comment: Do you have the same issue after commenting out the line `stepLbl.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));`?

Comment: Yes, with english strings i this problem are solved. And thank you for correcting the errors in my question. You have any idea why html tags with hebrew language string as JLabel text slowing down the win loading?

Comment: Why do those strings include non-Hebrew numbers? I would guess that mixing R-L (Hebrew) and L-R (English) would take longer for the HTML rendering engine to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some inefficiencies can be removed, like this (JLabel, Font creation):

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");
    for (String step : stepsArr) {
        sb.append(step).append("<br>");
    }
    JLabel stepLbl = new JLabel(sb.toString());
    stepLbl.setForeground(Color.black);
    stepLbl.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
    stepLbl.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    stepLbl.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 300);
    stepLbl.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 300));
    mainPanel.add(stepLbl);
```

Font, Hebrew and HTML rendering seem to be the major problem, but I have no actual experience. You might try to add `\u200E` (Left-to-Right) and `\u200F` (Right-to-Left) to see whether that makes some difference.

With HTML fonts can become even more tricky. Check that the same fonts are rendered, and not an additional.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");
    sb.append("<span style='font-family: Serif'>");
    for (String step : stepsArr) {
        sb.append(step).append("<br>");
    }
    sb.append("</span>");
```